# How to get the frameset from a frame window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, frames

Consider the following code:

```
function hide(aFrame) {
    var frameset = aFrame.frameset; //<-- this doesn't work
    $(frameset).attr('cols', '0,*');
}

//hide parent frame
hide(window.parent);

//hide current frame
hide(window);
```

I have a function that takes a frame and I would like to hide it by changing the `cols` of its frameset. jQuery may be used to answer the question (but a pure JavaScript solution is okay as well).

Comment: I'm sensing a distinct lack of jQuery in a question tagged with jQuery. Are you looking for an answer that does include some jQuery? Or should it be bare JavaScript the way it is written currently?

Comment: jQuery is allowed, but not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick seems to be querying the parent document:

```
function hide(aFrame) {
    var frameset = aFrame.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('frameset');
    $(frameset).attr('cols', '0,*');
}
```